# Bash: check if argument contains regex

Tags: regex, bash

```
    [[ $1 =~ .*\d+.* ]] && echo "The name must not contain digits" && exit 1

    echo "Oh no"
```

This script prints "Oh no" regardless if the first argument contains numeric characters or not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\d` is a PCRE extension. ERE (the POSIX regular expression standard) only guarantees `[[:digit:]]`. If you use `\d` in bash, it'll work on _some_ operating systems -- where the standard C library's regex functions are extended -- and not others; it's always more reliable to stick to what the standard guarantees.

Comment: BTW, `=~` doesn't do any implicit anchoring, so just `[[ $1 =~ [[:digit:]] ]]` will do; no need for the `.*`s.